# Is it possible to perform arithmetic operations on multidimensional arrays?

Tags: java

Here is my example:

```
    int myMultiDimenArray[][] = {{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
      for(int i=0;i<myMultiDimenArray.length;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<myMultiDimenArray.length;j++)
       {
          arrayTotal+=myMultiDimenArray[i][j];
       }
       System.out.println(arrayTotal);
```

This only prints out a total of 24.

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't know how it comes about"?

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of all the elements in the array?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  i expect it (that is if my code is correct) to print out 39

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes, that is what i want to do

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But you have to write your code correctly ... just like anything else in Java (or any other programming language).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i=0;i<myMultiDimenArray.length;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<myMultiDimenArray.length;j++)
       {
          arrayTotal+=myMultiDimenArray[i][j];
       }
}
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<myMultiDimenArray.length;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<myMultiDimenArray[i].length;j++)
       {
          arrayTotal+=myMultiDimenArray[i][j];
       }
}
```

Multidimensional arrays in Java are arrays of arrays. `myMultiDimenArray.length` is `2`, but each sub array has a length of `3`. You were computing 4+5+7+8, which equals 24.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your loops is that the inner loop should iterate the second dimension, not the first. Presently, your code iterates a 2x2 subarray of your 2x3 array; that is why you are getting 24 in place of 39.

```
for(int i=0;i<myMultiDimenArray.length;i++)
for(int j=0;j<myMultiDimenArray[i].length;j++)
   {
      arrayTotal+=myMultiDimenArray[i][j];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `j` with the length of a wrong array, so `j` end up `2` instead of `3`:

```
j<myMultiDimenArray.length
```

The condition should be:

```
j<myMultiDimenArray[i].length
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for(int i=0;i<myMultiDimenArray.length;i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<myMultiDimenArray[i].length;j++) {
          arrayTotal+=myMultiDimenArray[i][j];
      }
}
```

Otherwise `j` will go from `0` to the length of the **entire** array, not the inner array that you are currently getting with `i`.